# after installing ubuntu, system has become very slow

Tags: 14.04

I have Dell inspiron 15 R, 8GB RAM 1TB hard disk. I have only ubuntu 14.04 installed on it. But soon after installing, my system has become slow. I have tried reducing the swappiness to 10 from default 60 but still no use. Anything else that can be done..??

Comment: What's amount of swap space have you added to your system?  Which is the method you use to reduce swappiness?

Comment: gksudo leafpad /etc/sysctl.conf

Comment: Did you install ubuntu as dual boot or only as ubuntu on your harddisk?
Also, did you allocate swap area?
These may be the answers you are looking for.

Comment: # Decrease swap usage to a more reasonable level
vm.swappiness=10
Added these 2 lines in sysctl.comf to reduce swappiness to 10

Comment: I have the some computer, and found that changing the disk scheduler helped me quite a bit - I will post as an answer below

Comment: Its not dual boot. My system has only ubuntu. I didnot allocate any swap area while installing..

Comment: @AbhishekSharmaM - OK, the other thing to ask is what makes the computer feel slow:  Is it a graphics performance issue?  Have you checked `top` to see if something is taking up huge amounts of CPU time?  Please execute `glxinfo | grep renderer`  and paste the results into your original question.  You may have to `sudo apt-get install mesa-utils` first.

Comment: abhishek@abhishek-Inspiron-7520:~$ glxinfo | grep renderer
OpenGL renderer string: AMD Radeon HD 7700M Series

Answer (score 1):

I have the same computer, and use a different disk scheduler.  Ubuntu has *cfq* available, which works pretty well.  I no longer use *cfq* but instead use a custom kernel with another scheduler, but use *cfq* when loading new versions of Ubuntu until I can recompile the kernel.

Additionally, I do keep swappiness very, very low. (1)

You can enable *cfq* in two methods:

Temporary method, form a terminal:

```
sudo -i
cd /sys/class/block/sda/queue
echo cfq > scheduler
exit
```

If this helps you, and you want to make it a permanent change, if should be placed into grub.

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Look for the line starting `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` and modify it so that it reads

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash elevator=cfq"`

Exit `nano` (press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>o</kbd> then <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd>) and then enter the command

`sudo update-grub`

After a reboot, *cfq* will be enabled which you can detect by

```
cat /sys/class/block/sda/queue/scheduler
```

Comment: No charles. changing scheduler to cfq didn't help me.